# CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics-engine

i am not using chipmunk, but with only PhysicsEngine, cocos 2d v3.

```
_physicsNode = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physicsNode.collisionDelegate = self;
_physicsNode.gravity=ccp(0,-165);
_physicsNode.debugDraw = TRUE;
[self addChild:_physicsNode];

CCNode *handAttachPoint=[CCNode node];
handAttachPoint.physicsBody.type=CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
handAttachPoint.position=ccp(self.contentSize.width/8,self.contentSize.height/2);
handAttachPoint.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1.0 andCenter:handAttachPoint.anchorPointInPoints];
//handAttachPoint.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[];
[_physicsNode addChild:handAttachPoint];
```

I want the node **handAttachPoint** to be static in the window, but it is still falling down..:(

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the order wrong here:

```
handAttachPoint.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;

...

handAttachPoint.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1.0
                               andCenter:handAttachPoint.anchorPointInPoints];
```

In the first line physicsBody hasn't been assigned yet, the property is nil. Assigning static doesn't do anything there, it is ignored. You have to perform this assignment **after** initializing and assigning the physics body.